# Running head wrong in endnotes chapter when using enotez package

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, endnotes, enotez

I use the `enotez` package (current version, 0.9a) for endnotes. When I print the endnotes (using `\printendnotes`), the running head of the endnotes chapter contains the name of the previous chapter instead of "Notes".

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter{Introduction}

First paragraph.\endnote{\lipsum{3}}

\lipsum{5}

Last paragraph.\endnote{\lipsum{3}}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

The behaviour is the same when I use KOMA-Script's `scrlayer-scrpage` package and configure the running head with `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` and `\automark{chapter}`.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if it is a bug. Is there a solution or workaround for fixing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emit the proper marks:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\setenotez{list-heading=\chapter*{#1\@mkboth{#1}{#1}}}                   
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter{Introduction}

First paragraph.\endnote{\lipsum{3}}

\lipsum{5}

New paragraph.\endnote{\lipsum{3}}

Last paragraph.\endnote{\lipsum{3}}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

As you're using `scrreport`, an easier way is available:

```latex
\setenotez{list-heading=\addchap{#1}}
```

In KOMA-Script lingo, this means “add an unnumbered chapter along with the corresponding entry in the table of contents”, not “add somebody to the party”.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why it fixes the issue, but it does. Thank you!

Comment: With class `scrreprt` you can use  `\setenotez{list-heading=\addchap{#1}}` to get the desired result.

Comment: @esdd As you see I'm not expert in these classes. The method I suggested works also for the standard classes. I know, KOMA-script classes are full of bell and whistles, but the manuals are unreadable and the name of commands not really good: why `\addchap` and not the clearer `\addchapter`? A *chap* in English is very different from a *chapter*.

Comment: @egreg Using KOMA-script I can avoid learning TeX, as you can easily see if you compare your solution with Elke's. Your solution needs internals of LaTeX (or even TeX?), Elke only needs a well documented command from KOMA-script. There is a price: Me, being a sole user of LaTeX, have to read the manual carefully. \\ I fully understand that you'll never need to study the manual, given your TeX-skills. But your understandable unwilligness to study the manual does not justify to depreciate it. The »scrguide« / »scrguien« is really written carefully.

Comment: @KeksDose I beg to disagree about `scrguien`. I consulted it many times, so I could make an opinion about it.

Comment: @egreg But you are not the intended reader, while I am. You are overqualified.

Comment: @esdd If egreg is overqualified, what about you?